# При запуске бота,прописываю команду /start и не появляется клавиатура

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    full_name = f'Привет, <u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u>, снизу можешь выбрать программу тренировок и узнать их стоимость.'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, full_name, parse_mode='html')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def keyboard(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    buttonA = types.KeyboardButton('Программа тренировок')
    buttonB = types.KeyboardButton('Стоимость')
    buttonC = types.KeyboardButton('Контакты и адреса')
    markup.row(buttonA, buttonB, buttonC)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот так вы не пробовали?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    full_name = f'Привет, <u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u>, снизу можешь выбрать программу тренировок и узнать их стоимость.'
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    buttonA = types.KeyboardButton('Программа тренировок')
    buttonB = types.KeyboardButton('Стоимость')
    buttonC = types.KeyboardButton('Контакты и адреса')
    markup.row(buttonA, buttonB, buttonC)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, full_name, reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')
```